# Vertex-deleted subgraphs isomorphic implies automorphism mapping one vertex to the other?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose two vertex-deleted subgraphs of an acyclic digraph G are isomorphic, where the deleted vertices v and w are both sinks.  Is there an automorphism of G mapping v to w?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to construct a counterexample.

Start with an unoriented cycle with a cyclic automorphism group (of order $\geq$ 3) generated by an automorphism $\varphi$. Insert arrows at vertices $a$ and $b=\varphi(a)$ pointing to new vertices $v$ and $w$ respectively.

[image]

The resulting graph $G$ has no non-trivial automorphisms, but the vertex-deleted subgraphs are isomorphic.

Comment: I don't see $v$ or $w$ in these diagrams. I don't see arrows at $a$ or $b$ pointing to anything other than $a$ and $b$. In short, I don't understand the diagrams.

Comment: These arrows are not drawn. Sorry about the confusion. What is the best way to draw graphs here at mathoverflow?

Comment: Maybe if you write out the adjacency matrices some talented individual will draw the graphs.

Comment: Dag, Gerry, thanks.  Brendan McKay gave me something similar that looks like Dag's "unoriented cycle" minus the two arrows on the right, with a vertex at each end of every arrow.  Deleting the 3rd and 6th vertices then works.  Also works if you add another right-pointing arrow to Dag's unoriented cycle and delete the 3rd and 9th vertices.

Comment: Works as a counterexample, I mean.

Comment: Ah, a good diagram is worth a thousand words!